# Cashier checks purchased in the 80's at a bank that is now closed - the State Treasury Dept can't find them

Tags: united-states, banking, check

My dad who is deceased purchased cashier checks in the 80's and the bank has since closed. I reached out to the States unclaimed property; they found several checks but there are a few left that they were unable to locate.

We went through probate and I am the executor of his estate. What can I do at this point to locate those funds?

Comment: you say he purchased cashiers checks. What does that mean? who were they made out to? why weren't they cashed?

Answer (score 3):

Don't know if you still need this information, but you need to check the trail of that bank and find out if it was merged into another one--for starters. If that is not so, you should search the actual check numbers on the state unclaimed property site for the state where the bank was when the checks were purchased. Also search your father's name. If it is merged, trail the bank to where the funds went from the closed bank.  Either way, what happened to the bank can be found on the FDIC website. Money never disappears, someone always has it. I have studied situations like this for years, and have experienced them.  Everything you need to know, some level of government knows and can tell you--you just need to know who to ask.